# Proper way to remember parameters accross requests in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following requirement for my first MVC site. I am finishing up.

Each page (there are 5) have some filter parameters on top.  I need to implement a quick and easy way to remember the parameters when the user uses the back and forth buttons or the button or the home button which i have added in the masterview.

For example.  the user could filter data in the first page for a given month, click the details on one line of the grid, they when he presses the home button on the second page, go back to the first page while remembering the filter he had specified at first.

thanks

Comment: What about sessions ?

Comment: Another option: Save the search with an ID, then reference that search ID as a parameter in the return link.

Comment: Can either of you give me a quick and dirty example, I am opened to either methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, imagine your filter is an object :

```
public class SearchFilterPage1 {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int SearchValueX {get;set;}
}
```

In your Get action

```
public ActionResult Index() {
  var filter = (SearchFilterPage1)HttpContext.Current.Sesssion["FilterPage1"]
                       ?? new SearchFilterPage1();

  var model = someMethodForSearching(filter);
  return View(model);
}
```

And when your filter change (let's say you use a post action)

```
public ActionResult Filter(SearchFilterPage1 filter) {
   HttpContext.Current.Session["FilterPage1"] = filter;
   return something;
}
```

You can then use a different Key in Session for each page's filter if you want, clear them when you want / need, etc.

Comment: Fitler is the most despicable of filters. +1 though

Answer (score 0):

If you put your filter parameters into URL using proper routing it would work as it is, because the url will be the state and the back and forward button cycle from one url/state to another. You do not need to implement nothing.